# Group data frame columns by their dates (which comprise column titles) and summarize instances of 1s and 0s in R

Tags: r, date, merge, dplyr, grouping

I have a bit of annoying coding problem, about which I'd appreciate your assistance.

Here are some sample data:

```
ID     "2013-03-20"    "2013-04-09"    "2013-04-11"    "2013-04-17"    
5167f            0               0               0               1  
1214m            0               0               0               0  
1844f            0               1               1               0  
2113m            0               0               1               1
```

Here's the rub: notice how the column names of the sample data frame comprise dates, and some dates can be close to one another. The `ID` column is a simple unique identifier for the observations.

Here are my goals:

(1) I'd like to be able to first group the columns by whether or not they each fall within a 2-week (or 14-day) range (i.e. that is defined by 2-week increments starting on `"2013-03-20"` until `"2016-12-20"`); thus, if they do fall within the same range, they'd receive the same identifier (for a new data frame; e.g., `Period1` for any dates that fall between `"2013-03-20"` and `"2013-04-03"`).

(2) Once all of the date columns are assigned to a particular period, I then want to summarize the cell data (of 0s and 1s) per period in the following way: if any `1` appears in a particular period for an individual (at all) then that individual would receive a `1` for the whole period (also, if the individual only has 0s for that period, then it would receive a `0` for that single period).

(3) Once this workflow is defined, I then want to group the dates by seasons and years based on their month codes (e.g., `WinterYYYY` = December, January, February; `SpringYYYY` = March, April, May; `SummerYYYY` = June, July, August; and `FallYYYY` = September, October, November) to produce a new data frame.

In summary, to demonstrate the products manually:

(End Product for Goals 1 and 2; i.e. for just first two columns in the sample data [date ranges in parentheses are just for a guide])

```
ID     Period1 ("2013-03-20" - "2013-04-03")        Period2 ("2013-04-04" - "2013-04-18")      
5167f                                    0                                 1    
1214m                                    0                                 0    
1844f                                    0                                 1    
2113m                                    0                                 1
```

(End Product for Goals 2 and 3; i.e. for all columns in the sample data [month ranges in parentheses are just for a guide])

```
ID                Spring2013  (March - May)    
5167f                                    1  
1214m                                    0  
1844f                                    1  
2113m                                    1
```

Perhaps, something from the `dplyr` package could be useful, but I'm not quite sure.

Thank you for any help, in advance. Please feel free to ask any follow-up questions for clarifications.

-AD-

Comment: if you are working with the column why not transpose the `DateFrame`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using functions from `tidyverse`.

```
# Load packages
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

# Create example data frames
dt <- fread("ID     '2013-03-20'    '2013-04-09'    '2013-04-11'    '2013-04-17'    
5167f            0               0               0               1  
                 1214m            0               0               0               0  
                 1844f            0               1               1               0  
                 2113m            0               0               1               1")
```

The key is to prepare a table showing the association between date and grouping variable, such as period, month, or season. In this example, `dt_merge` is such table.

```
dt_merge <- data_frame(
  # Create a column showing the beginning date
  Date1 = seq(from = ymd("2013-03-20"), to = ymd("2016-12-20"), by = "2 weeks")) %>%
  # Create  a column showing the end date of each period
  mutate(Date2 = lead(Date1)) %>%
  # Adjust Date1
  mutate(Date1 = if_else(Date1 == ymd("2013-03-20"), Date1, Date1 + 1)) %>%
  # Remove the last row
  drop_na(Date2) %>%
  # Create date list
  mutate(Dates = map2(Date1, Date2, function(x, y){ seq(x, y, by = "day") })) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  # Create Group ID
  mutate(RunID = group_indices_(., dots. = c("Date1", "Date2"))) %>%
  # Create Period ID
  mutate(Period = paste0("Period", RunID)) %>%
  # Add a column showing Month
  mutate(Month = month(Dates)) %>%
  # Add a column showing Year
  mutate(Year = year(Dates)) %>%
  # Add a column showing season
  mutate(Season = case_when(
    Month %in% 3:5            ~ "Spring",
    Month %in% 6:8            ~ "Summer",
    Month %in% 9:11           ~ "Fall",
    Month %in% c(12, 1, 2)    ~ "Winter",
    TRUE                      ~ NA_character_
  )) %>%
  # Combine Season and Year
  mutate(SeasonYear = paste0(Season, Year)) %>%
  select(-Date1, -Date2, -RunID)
```

After this step, it becomes easy to generate the output you want to. In this example, `dt3` is the first end product. `dt4` is the second product.

```
dt2 <- dt %>%
  # Reshape the data frame
  gather(Date, Value, -ID) %>%
  # Convert Date to date class
  mutate(Date = ymd(Date)) %>%
  # Join dt_merge
  left_join(dt_merge, by = c("Date" = "Dates"))

# Product 1
dt3 <- dt2 %>%
  group_by(ID, Period) %>%
  summarise(Value = max(Value)) %>%
  spread(Period, Value)

# Product 2
dt4 <- dt2 
  group_by(ID, SeasonYear) %>%
  summarise(Value = max(Value)) %>%
  spread(SeasonYear, Value)
```

Comment: Thank you for this comprehensive answer, @ycw. I have yet to test it fully, but after giving it a first try, I hit an unresolved error `could not find function 'if_else'` in the `dt_merge` section, despite having already called the `dplyr` library. Do you know how I might correct this issue?

Comment: `if_else` is in dplyr `0.7.1` (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.1/topics/if_else). update your dplyr to latest version could be helpful. Otherwise I have not idea.

Comment: Thanks, @ycw. That was the solution. My version of `dplyr` was being installed from an out-of-date snapshot repository. Your answer provides the precise solution. Much appreciated!

Comment: I am glad to help. If this answer is useful, please accept it by marking the green symbol on the top left.

Comment: any thoughts as to why all possible Periods will not populate output after the join step of the code? I adjusted your solution to group dates by 1-week intervals recently, but I noticed that final output after the left_join (e.g., for dt3) did not include all possible week intervals (i.e. 1-145) for a new full time period of "2013-03-20" to "2015-12-31." I can post code tomorrow, to help clarify this, if my description doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Andrew If possible, post your code as a new question and accept this solution as the answer to this post if it works for this example. This is how Stack Overflow works. If you changed the original post, you will make my solution looks "wrong". It is tedious and time-consuming for me to update my answer. On the other hand, a new question will attract others' attention. You will have a higher chance to get the help you need.

Comment: new question and code posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45983806/grouping-a-data-frame-by-dates-resolve-missing-time-periods-bug.

Answer (score 1):

Please put your data in a tidy format first.

```
library(dplyr)
data <- gather(data, date, value, -ID )
```

Then try:

```
library(lubridate)
data$date  <- ymd(data$date)
data <-  mutate(data, period = date - as.Date("2013-03-20")) #difference in days
data <- mutate(data, period2 = ceiling(as.numeric(data$period)/14))
data$period2 <- ifelse(data$period2 == 0, 1, data$period2) #change period 0 to period 1

newdat <- data %>% 
          group_by(ID, period2) %>%
          summarise(result = ifelse(sum(value)>0, 1, 0))
```

Use the `spread()` function to change back to the original format.