# Grouping a data frame by dates: resolve missing time periods' bug

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, lubridate, tidyverse

I've identified, if not myself created, a difficult bug to resolve in some nice code received from a generous respondent here on StackOverflow a few weeks ago, and I could use some new assistance today.

Sample data (called object `eh` below):

```
    ID        2013-03-20 2013-04-09 2013-04-11 2013-04-17 2013-04-25 2013-05-15 2013-05-24 2013-05-25 2013-05-26
    5167f          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0
    1214m          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0
    1844f          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0
    2113m          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0
    2254m          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0
    2721f          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0
    3121f          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0
    3486f          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0
    3540f          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0
    4175m          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0
```

I need to be able to group `0s` and `1s` by the time period in which their respective column date falls (e.g., every 1, 2, 3, or 4 weeks). Whenever a `1` falls at least once within a specific date range (`Period`), then a `1` is summarized for that `ID` in that `Period` (`0`, else).

I'm starting with the 1-week summary routine as an example. My main problem is that the final output generated lacks some of the total possible 1-week `Periods` during the time series `"2013-03-20"` to `"2015-12-31"`.

Notice in this example output, wherein the rows are for unique `IDs` and columns are for unique `Periods`, how `Periods` 2, 5, 7, and 9 are missing:

```
    1   3   4   6   8   10  11  12  13  14
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Here is the full routine for grouping the original data frame (see sample data shared above):

```
    #Convert to data table from original data frame, eh
    dt <- as.data.table(eh)

    #One week summarized encounter histories
    dt_merge <- data_frame(
      # Create a column showing the beginning date
      Date1 = seq(from = ymd("2013-03-20"), to = ymd("2015-12-31"), by = "1 week")) %>%
      # Create  a column showing the end date of each period
      mutate(Date2 = lead(Date1)) %>%
      # Adjust Date1
      mutate(Date1 = if_else(Date1 == ymd("2013-03-20"), Date1, Date1 + 1)) %>%
      # Remove the last row
      drop_na(Date2) %>%
      # Create date list
      mutate(Dates = map2(Date1, Date2, function(x, y){ seq(x, y, by = "day") })) %>%
      unnest() %>%
      # Create Group ID
      mutate(RunID = group_indices_(., dots. = c("Date1", "Date2"))) %>%
      # Create Period ID
      mutate(Period = paste0(RunID)) %>%
      # Add a column showing Month
      mutate(Month = month(Dates)) %>%
      # Add a column showing Year
      mutate(Year = year(Dates)) %>%
      # Add a column showing season
      mutate(Season = case_when(
        Month %in% 3:5            ~ "Spring",
        Month %in% 6:8            ~ "Summer",
        Month %in% 9:11           ~ "Fall",
        Month %in% c(12, 1, 2)    ~ "Winter",
        TRUE                      ~ NA_character_
      )) %>%
      # Combine Season and Year
      mutate(SeasonYear = paste0(Season, Year)) %>%
      select(-Date1, -Date2, -RunID)
    dt2 <- dt %>%
      # Reshape the data frame
      gather(Date, Value, -ID) %>%
      # Convert Date to date class
      mutate(Date = ymd(Date)) %>%
      # Join dt_merge
      left_join(dt_merge, by = c("Date" = "Dates")) 
    one.week <- dt2 %>%
      group_by(ID, Period) %>%
      summarise(Value = max(Value)) %>%
      spread(Period, Value)

    #Finished product
    one.week <- as.data.frame(one.week)

    #Missing weeks 2, 5, 7, and 9...
    one.week
```

Can someone help me understand where I've gone wrong? Thanks in advance!

-AD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because those weeks are missing from the `eh` data. For example, if you look at the dates that make up week 2:

```
dt_merge %>%
  filter(Period == 2)
#> # A tibble: 7 x 6
#>        Dates Period Month  Year Season SeasonYear
#>       <date>  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>  <chr>      <chr>
#> 1 2013-03-28      2     3  2013 Spring Spring2013
#> 2 2013-03-29      2     3  2013 Spring Spring2013
#> 3 2013-03-30      2     3  2013 Spring Spring2013
#> 4 2013-03-31      2     3  2013 Spring Spring2013
#> 5 2013-04-01      2     4  2013 Spring Spring2013
#> 6 2013-04-02      2     4  2013 Spring Spring2013
#> 7 2013-04-03      2     4  2013 Spring Spring2013
```

You can see that none of these dates are in the columns of `eh`, which skip from 2013-03-20 to 2013-04-09. Because you use a `left_join` when creating `dt2`, only dates (and therefore weeks) in `eh` are retained.

This can be corrected by using `complete()` from the **tidyr** package to create the missing combinations of ID and Date.

```
dt2 <- dt %>%
  # Reshape the data frame
  gather(Date, Value, -ID) %>%
  # Convert Date to date class
  mutate(Date = ymd(Date)) %>%
  # Create missing ID/Date combinations
  complete(ID, Date = dt_merge$Dates) %>%
  # Join dt_merge
  left_join(dt_merge, by = c("Date" = "Dates"))
one.week <- dt2 %>%
  mutate(Period = as.numeric(Period)) %>%
  group_by(ID, Period) %>%
  summarise(Value = max(Value, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  spread(Period, Value)
one.week
#> # A tibble: 10 x 146
#> # Groups:   ID [10]
#>       ID   `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`   `6`   `7`   `8`   `9`  `10`  `11`
#>  * <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 1214m     0  -Inf     0     0  -Inf     0  -Inf     0  -Inf     0  -Inf
#>  2 1844f     0  -Inf     0     0  -Inf     0  -Inf     0  -Inf     0  -Inf
#>  3 2113m     0  -Inf     0     0  -Inf     0  -Inf     0  -Inf     0  -Inf
#>  4 2254m     0  -Inf     0     0  -Inf     0  -Inf     0  -Inf     0  -Inf
#>  5 2721f     0  -Inf     0     0  -Inf     0  -Inf     0  -Inf     0  -Inf
#>  6 3121f     0  -Inf     0     0  -Inf     0  -Inf     0  -Inf     0  -Inf
#>  7 3486f     0  -Inf     0     0  -Inf     0  -Inf     0  -Inf     0  -Inf
#>  8 3540f     0  -Inf     0     0  -Inf     0  -Inf     0  -Inf     0  -Inf
#>  9 4175m     0  -Inf     0     0  -Inf     0  -Inf     0  -Inf     0  -Inf
#> 10 5167f     0  -Inf     0     0  -Inf     0  -Inf     0  -Inf     0  -Inf
#> # ... with 134 more variables: `12` <dbl>, `13` <dbl>, `14` <dbl>,
#> #   `15` <dbl>, `16` <dbl>, `17` <dbl>, `18` <dbl>, `19` <dbl>,
#> #   `20` <dbl>, `21` <dbl>, `22` <dbl>, `23` <dbl>, `24` <dbl>,
#> #   `25` <dbl>, `26` <dbl>, `27` <dbl>, `28` <dbl>, `29` <dbl>,
#> #   `30` <dbl>, `31` <dbl>, `32` <dbl>, `33` <dbl>, `34` <dbl>,
#> #   `35` <dbl>, `36` <dbl>, `37` <dbl>, `38` <dbl>, `39` <dbl>,
#> #   `40` <dbl>, `41` <dbl>, `42` <dbl>, `43` <dbl>, `44` <dbl>,
#> #   `45` <dbl>, `46` <dbl>, `47` <dbl>, `48` <dbl>, `49` <dbl>,
#> #   `50` <dbl>, `51` <dbl>, `52` <dbl>, `53` <dbl>, `54` <dbl>,
#> #   `55` <dbl>, `56` <dbl>, `57` <dbl>, `58` <dbl>, `59` <dbl>,
#> #   `60` <dbl>, `61` <dbl>, `62` <dbl>, `63` <dbl>, `64` <dbl>,
#> #   `65` <dbl>, `66` <dbl>, `67` <dbl>, `68` <dbl>, `69` <dbl>,
#> #   `70` <dbl>, `71` <dbl>, `72` <dbl>, `73` <dbl>, `74` <dbl>,
#> #   `75` <dbl>, `76` <dbl>, `77` <dbl>, `78` <dbl>, `79` <dbl>,
#> #   `80` <dbl>, `81` <dbl>, `82` <dbl>, `83` <dbl>, `84` <dbl>,
#> #   `85` <dbl>, `86` <dbl>, `87` <dbl>, `88` <dbl>, `89` <dbl>,
#> #   `90` <dbl>, `91` <dbl>, `92` <dbl>, `93` <dbl>, `94` <dbl>,
#> #   `95` <dbl>, `96` <dbl>, `97` <dbl>, `98` <dbl>, `99` <dbl>,
#> #   `100` <dbl>, `101` <dbl>, `102` <dbl>, `103` <dbl>, `104` <dbl>,
#> #   `105` <dbl>, `106` <dbl>, `107` <dbl>, `108` <dbl>, `109` <dbl>,
#> #   `110` <dbl>, `111` <dbl>, ...
```

Here `-Inf` is returned if there were no values for that ID in a given week. Alternatively, instead of filling the missing values with `NA`, they could be filled with, for example 0, using `complete(ID, Date = dt_merge$Dates, fill = list(Value = 0))`. This will make the Value variable 0 for any of the unobserved ID and Date combinations.

Comment: This is it. Thank you very much!